# Webpack - --watchnot working

Tags: angular, webpack

When I create Angular2 project, webpack watch all changes and start recompile. I reinstall Windows, clear project folder of trash and get strange webpack behavior. When I change file content - webpack recompile, and when I change file a second time webpack didn't want start recompile. Why???

*webpack.config.js*

```js
var path = require('path');
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./config/html-elements-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/main.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './dist/app.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts/,
                loaders: ['ts-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "html"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["raw", "sass"]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve('src'),
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 7777,
        contentBase: '.',
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    watch: true,
    cache: false
}
```

Run webpack by this command:

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --hot
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution!

For delepment I use Intellij 2016.2.5 In this IDE I have this strange error behavior. I installed SublimeText3 and start tested with this edior. And vuala! After every change file content I see that Webapack start recompile.

I go to Intellij settings and disable **Use "sage write(save changes to a temporary file start)"**

[image]